# Python-Flask Project Login Function Error: "Bad Request - The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

Tags: python, flask

My Project has been built with Frontend is React.js and Backend is Python-Flask.

When I try to login by using existing user info on Chrome Browser, I am getting one error below.

> **Bad Request** The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
> [image]

And then, when I check api with same user info on Postman, it returns the success results.
[image]

Here is my codebase.

**Login Function on Frontend.**

```
export const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    const token = await fetch(`${API_URL}/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password
        })
    }).then(res => res.json())
    return token
}
```

**Login Route on Python-Flask Backend**

```
@auth.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    post_data = request.get_json()
    try:
        user = User.query.filter_by(email = post_data.get('email')).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(
            user.password, post_data.get('password')
        ):
            auth_token = create_access_token(identity=post_data.get('email'))
            if auth_token:
                responseObject = {
                    'status': 'success',
                    'message': 'Successfully logged in.',
                    'auth_token': auth_token,
                    'user': user.toObject()
                }
                return jsonify(responseObject), 200
        else:
            responseObject = {
                'status': 'fail',
                'message': 'User does not exist'
            }
            return jsonify(responseObject), 404
    except Exception as e:
        responseObject = {
            'status': 'fail', 
            'message': 'Try again'
        }
        return jsonify(responseObject), 500
```

What is wrong here?
Why I am getting good return values on **Postman**, but I am getting **Bad Request Error** on Browser?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I found a solution to fix the Bad Request 400 error problem above.
It was a front-end issue, not a back-end issue.

I updated the `login function` as shown below.

**Old Login Function:**

```
export const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    const token = await fetch(`${API_URL}/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email,
            password
        })
    }).then(res => res.json())
    return token
}
```

**Updated Login Function:**

```
export const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  const apiUrl = API_URL + '/auth/login'

  const requestOptions: any = {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email,
      password
    })
  }

  const token = await fetch(apiUrl, requestOptions)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok')
      }
      console.log('Login Token Response', response)
      return response.json()
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error:', error)
    })
  return token
}
```

After updating like this, Bad Request Error disappeared.

**If you have a better solution, please let me know.**

Thanks.